# scala iterator and stream example. stream fails on reuse

Tags: scala, stream, iterator

I have a code (`sentences` is `iterator` here):

```
  def count() = {
    var count = 0
    for(sentence <- sentences.toStream) count += sentence.words.size
    count
  }
```

and test:

```
// first
val wordCount1 = wordCounter.count()
wordCount1 must_== 10

// second time - should be same result
val wordCount2 = wordCounter.count()
wordCount2 must_== 10   // fails: result is 0
```

Last test fails:

```
'0' is not equal to '10'
Expected :10
Actual   :0
```

But since I use `sentences.toStream` in the code above, I suppose to have `stream` at it is (*I can reuse it, theoretically*).

**Q: why does it fail?**

---

**EDIT:**
I was hoping that `toStream` would help. Like  was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala):   (..."You can traverse the same `Stream` multiple times"...). It's like I never touch iterator, I have deal with stream.

But I got.. `sentences.toStream` **used UP** `sentence-iterator` so I can not use it anymore. I just expected when doing `toStream` on `iterator` is do a logic like getting stream-'link' to iterator without touching iterator itself. Ok..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because the `sentences` `Iterator` has been expended. One is not suppose to call an `Iterator` after a method on it has been called except for the `next` and `hasNext` methods.

A simple example shows this:

```
scala> val it = Iterator(1,2,3)
it: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> it.foreach(println(_))
1
2
3

scala> it.foreach(println(_))

scala>
```

In your case `sentences` has been expended on the first call and is empty on the second one giving a size of 0.

Calling `toStream` on it does not change this. You get back an empty `Stream`. If you want to reuse `sentences` assign it to a list with `val l = sentences.toList` before calling count.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `toStream` helps. I just changed the code to expect `stream` but not `iterator`, in order not trying create stream from 'dead' iterator on second+ traverse.

Then my solution is:

```
val stream = new SentenceFileReader("two_lines_file.txt").toStream

val wordCounter = new WordCounter(stream) // now it accepts stream but not iterator

// first
val wordCount1 = wordCounter.count()
wordCount1 must_== 10

// second time - same result
val wordCount2 = wordCounter.count()
wordCount2 must_== 10
```