# Bash: Split a file in linux in 10 pieces only by blank lines

Tags: linux, bash, file, scala, split

I am currently working with some files to parse with a Scala app. The problem is that the files are too large so they always end up throwing an exception in the heap size (and I've tried with the max heap size I can and still no use).

Now, the files looks like this:

```
This is
one paragraph
for Scala
to parse

This is
another paragraph
for Scala
to parse

Yet another
paragraph
```

And so on. Basically I would like to take all this files and split them in 10 or 20 pieces each, but I have to be sure a paragraph is not splitted in half in the results. Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255021/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-scala-stream-class

Comment: That's not use for me :/ I already do it. Still, I have to have all the parsed paragraph in the app, it is simpler to have smaller files than to change all my program logic (plus I don't have much time to do it)

Comment: The question is tagged with bash: So what about splitting it in a separate Scala program?

Comment: I finally solved the way Brian said, with a lazy iterator. Had to change some of the logic of the program but wasn't as much as I originally thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an awk script that will break up input files into `batch_size` blocks ( with a garbage trailing record separating newline ).  Put this into a file and change it into an executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; last_f=""; batch_size=20}

# perform setup whenever the filename changes
FILENAME!=last_f {r_per_f=calc_r_per_f(); incr_out(); last_f=FILENAME; fnum=1}

# write a record to an output file
{print $0 > out}

# after a batch, change the file name
(FNR%r_per_f)==0 {incr_out()}

# function to roll the file name
function incr_out() {close(out); fnum++; out=FILENAME"_"fnum".out"}

# function to get the number of records per file
function calc_r_per_f() {
    cmd=sprintf( "grep \"^$\" %s | wc -l", FILENAME )
    cmd | getline rcnt
    close(cmd)
    return( sprintf( "%d", rcnt/batch_size ) )
    }
```

You would change the `batch_size` element in the begin block to adjust the number of output files per input file and the output file name itself can be altered by changing the `out=` assignment in `incr_out()`.

If you put it into a file called `awko`, you would run it like `awko data1 data2` and get files like `data2_7.out` for example.  Of course the output names are more horrible than that if your input file names have extensions etc.

Comment: Very complicated to make what we (me,fredtantini...) purposed in our comments. That does exactly the same... isn't it ? - sorry, I just understood that you allow to split in "n" files, as we set "n" paragraphs in our solutions

Comment: It's not so complicated (only 3 actions) and is indeed similar.  It allows for `~n` individual files from each input file like the other solutions.  It differs in that it `close()s` each file when done with them, the output files are related to the input file names and each input file is broken up into roughly the same number of sub-files as the others(`calc_r_per_f()`).  It should work the same when called like `awko data1 data2 data3 data4 ...` as `awko data1` + `awko data2` +... .  The functions reduce copied code and keep the action blocks short.  Let me know if I can improve the comments.

Answer (score 7):

`csplit file.txt /^$/ {*}`

`csplit` splits a file separated by the specified pattern.

`/^$/` matches empty lines.

`{*}` repeats the previous pattern indefinitely.

Comment: My file looks similar to crscardellino's, but in my case output for this command was:
"483\n150".
These numbers do not appear in the file.
What do they represent?
Is this expected output?
I have "csplit (GNU coreutils) 9.0".

Answer (score 2):

to split every 3 paragraphs:

```
awk 'BEGIN{nParMax=3;npar=0;nFile=0}
     /^$/{npar++;if(npar==nParMax){nFile++;npar=0;next}}
     {print $0 > "foo."nFile}' foo.orig
```

to split every 10 lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{nLineMax=10;nline=0;nFile=0}
    /^$/{if(nline>=nLineMax){nFile++;nline=0;next}}
    {nline++;print $0 > "foo."nFile}' foo.orig
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, upvoted! If you don't mind, with this pattern `/^$/` I'm getting the job done 99.99% of the time. However, once in a time, I'm getting "paragraph" splitted randomly  in the middle of a line. Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "split" command, but as you want to split paragraphs, you can use this kind of script:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" 'BEGIN {n=1}{print $0 > "file"n++".txt"}' yourfile.txt
```

That split each paragraph in file named "file1.txt", "file2.txt", and so on...

To set "n++" each "N" paragraph, you can do:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" 'BEGIN{n=1; i=0; nbp=100}{if (i++ == nbp) {i=0; n++} print $0 > "file"n".txt"}' yourfile.txt
```

Just change "nbp" value to setup the paragraph numbers

Comment: The problem with this way is that paragraphs can become too many (a file can hold oveer 100k paragraph and the files are over 50) :/

Comment: You can update "n" each N paragraph, I can edit my command to set it up

Comment: `csplit` allows you to split by pattern instead of size.

Answer (score 0):

To split a file of X paragraphs into n (`10` below) files where X is some number greater than or equal to n would be:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -n 10 '
    NR==FNR { totParas=NR; parasPerFile=2; next }
    (FNR % parasPerFile) == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME "_out" (++c)
        parasLeft = totParas - (FNR - 1)
        parasPerFile = int(parasLeft/n) + (parasLeft%n ? 1 : 0)
    }
    { print > out }
' file file
```