# Reading very large files (~ 1 TB) in sequential blocks

Tags: scala, large-files

I need to read a large file in Scala and process it in blocks of k bits (k could be 65536 typically). As a simple example (but not what I want):

file blocks are `(f1, f2, ... fk)`.

I want to compute `SHA256(f1)+SHA256(f2)+...+ SHA256(fk)`

Such a computation can be done incrementally using only constant storage and the current block without needing other blocks.

What is the best way to read the file? (perhaps something that uses continuations?)

EDIT: The linked question kind of solves the problem but not always, as the file I am looking at contains binary data.

Comment: @Christian, No, this isn't duplicate of the question cited.

Comment: I can't understand how this is a duplicate with the question cited. The other question talks about a text based csv file, this question is dealing with a "not text based csv" file. The answers of the other question should not apply. I really doubting who ever marked this as duplicate if they read the both questions fully.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach using Akka Streams. This uses constant memory and and can process the file chunks as they are read.

See the "Streaming File IO" at the bottom of this page for more info. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-io.html

Start with a simple `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-experimental" % "1.0-RC3"
)
```

The interesting parts are the `Source`, `Flow`, and `Sink`. The `Source` is a `SynchronousFileSource` that reads in a large file with a chunk size of `65536`. A `ByteString` of chunk size is emitted from the `Source` and consumed by a `Flow` which calculates a SHA256 hash for each chunk. Lastly, the `Sink` consumes the output from the `Flow` and prints the byte arrays out. You'll want to convert these and sum them using a `fold` to get a total sum.

```
import akka.stream.io._
import java.io.File
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer
import java.security.MessageDigest

object LargeFile extends App{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
  import system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorFlowMaterializer()

   val file = new File("<path to large file>")

   val fileSource = SynchronousFileSource(file, 65536)

   val shaFlow = fileSource.map(chunk => sha256(chunk.toString))

   shaFlow.to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run//TODO - Convert the byte[] and sum them using fold

   def sha256(s: String) = {
     val  messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
     messageDigest.digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
   }
}
```

BYTE ARRAYS!

```
> run
[info] Running LargeFile 
[B@3d0587a6
[B@360cc296
[B@7fbb2192
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the digest using the stream continually, which I believe produces a iterator

```
import java.File
import java.FileInputStream
import java.security.MessageDigest

val file = new File("test.in")
val is = new FileInputStream(file)

val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")

val bytes = Array.fill[Byte](65536)(0)

Stream
    .continually((is.read(bytes),bytes))
    .takeWhile(_._1 != -1)
    .foreach{ x => md.update(x._2,0,x._1) }

println(md.digest())
// prinln(md.digest().map("%02X" format _).mkString) // if you want hex string
```

Comment: cala.collection.immutable.Stream is memoized, which would read the whole thing into memory (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255021/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-scala-stream-class#answer-4255338)