# How do I define a function parameter default associated with a generic parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming

I am attempting to refactor a function ([found towards the end of this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283624/501113)) to make it slightly more generic. Here's the original function definition:

```
def tryProcessSource(
  file: File,
  parseLine: (Int, String) => Option[List[String]] =
    (index, unparsedLine) => Some(List(unparsedLine)),
  filterLine: (Int, List[String]) => Option[Boolean] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(true),
  retainValues: (Int, List[String]) => Option[List[String]] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(parsedValues)
): Try[List[List[String]]] = {
  ???
}
```

And here is to what I am attempting to change it:

```
def tryProcessSource[A <: Any](
  file: File,
  parseLine: (Int, String) => Option[List[String]] =
    (index, unparsedLine) => Some(List(unparsedLine)),
  filterLine: (Int, List[String]) => Option[Boolean] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(true),
  transformLine: (Int, List[String]) => Option[A] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(parsedValues)
): Try[List[A]] = {
  ???
}
```

I keep getting a highlight error in the IntelliJ editor on `Some(parsedValues)` which says, "Expression of type Some[List[String]] doesn't conform to expected type Option[A]". I've been unable to figure out how to properly modify the function definition to satisfy the required condition; i.e. so the error goes away.

If I change `transformLine` to this (replace the generic parameter `A` with `Any`)...

```
transformLine: (Int, List[String]) => Option[Any] =
  (index, parsedValues) => Some(parsedValues)
```

...the error goes away. But, I also lose the strong typing associated with the generic parameter.

Any assistance on with this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, how can you convert a `List[String]` into an arbitrary `A`? It doesn't really make sense, unless you have some evidence to convert a `List[String]` to an `A` already. Some serious refactoring using type-classes could work, but I don't think it makes a lot of sense to have the default parameter anymore.

Comment: @m-z I now think I understand what you are saying. Please see the answer I just posted and let me know if you seen anything wrong or could be improved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In `transformLine: (Int, List[String]) => Option[A] = (index, parsedValues) => whatever`, `parsedValues` obviously has type `List[String]`, and so `Some(parsedValues)` is `Some[List[String]]`. There is simply no reasonable default value for `transformLine`.

You can change its type to `(Int, A) => Option[A]` or `(Int, List[A]) => Option[List[A]]` depending on what you need, and change the previous arguments as well, but you'll get stuck on the fact that lines are `String`s, so you'll have to convert them to `A` *somewhere*.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The point of `transformLine` is to take the index and the parsed string values from a specific line and convert them to an optional arbitrary type. Converting is the whole point of the `transformLine` function. And since the function can return `Option[+Any]`, why doesn't `Some[List[String]]` conform to `Option[+Any]`. IOW, if I change it explicitly to `Option[Any]` (as opposed to Option[A]), then the error disappears and `Some(parsedValue)` works fine.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium - Your default `transformLine` doesn't transform the line to an arbitrary type, it only works for `String`, which is why you get the error. An `Option[Any]` is different to an `Option[A]` since the client chooses `A` while the function can easily choose an `Any`.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Okay, I think I now understand what you are saying. I've now created an answer to my question which more explicitly and concretely expresses what you are implying.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Suppose someone calls `tryProcessSource[Int](file)` (leaving the other arguments as default). Then `transformLine` needs to have type `(Int, List[String]) => Option[Int]`, which your default value doesn't.

Comment: I now think I got it. Please read the answer I just posted to make sure I really did get it. And any feedback you can give me on the guideline/principle I highlighted is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and re-reading Alexey Romonov's answer and Lee's comment, it gave me a clue into how to refactor this to get it working. Additionally, I think it might also implies a guideline regarding providing default values to a function.

If I am understand it correctly, I am trying to combine a concrete, in this example case `List[String]` in the transform parameter default, with a generic type, in this case `Option[A]`. Essentially, this overlaps the boundary upon which a generic copy of the function is instantiated by the compiler for the specific user provided type and the explicitly provided `List[String]`. This leads me to the following guideline regarding defining generic functions:

> When transforming a concrete function to make it generic, 
>   each parameter with a default value which interacts directly with any of the generic parameters likely needs to
>   be removed and placed into an enclosing concrete function which forwards the call to the generic function.

---

So with this guideline in mind, let's rework the original code...

The concrete function looks like this (very similar to the original pre-generic-ified version which also included the desired concrete default parameters):

```
def tryProcessSource(
  file: File,
  parseLine: (Int, String) => Option[List[String]] =
    (index, unparsedLine) => Some(List(unparsedLine)),
  filter: (Int, List[String]) => Option[Boolean] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(true),
  transform: (Int, List[String]) => Option[List[String]] =
    (index, parsedValues) => Some(parsedValues)
): Try[List[List[String]]] =
  tryProcessSourceGeneric(file, parseLine, filter, transform)
```

And the generic-ified function looks like this (notice the lack of any parameter default values):

```
def tryProcessSourceGeneric[A, B](
  file: File,
  parseLine: (Int, String) => Option[A],
  filter: (Int, A) => Option[Boolean]
  transform: (Int, A) => Option[B]
): Try[List[B]] = {
  ???
}
```

Again, a huge thank you to Alexey and Lee for helping me struggle through this.

Comment: It can make sense for parameters involving generics to have default values. In your example, you could still have the same default value for `filterLine`, because it works for any `A`. Or if you remove the `B` parameter and have `transform: (Int, A) => Option[A]`, then `(_, x) => Some(x)` is a reasonable default value.

Comment: Awesome! So my guideline holds for `filter` and my existing `transform`. However, it doesn't hold for your `transform` example. Hmmm...not sure how to reword it. Mulling...