# How to return a line iterator on a big text file in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a gigantic 2GB text file which I want to read line by line without pushing everything to memory. I have written the following code snippet for that but it doesn't seem to work at `yield` call. How should I return the line iterator from a function then?

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, File, FileInputStream, InputStream, InputStreamReader}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def readLines(fileName: String): Iterable[String] = {
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    for (line <- bufferedReader.readLine()) {
        yield line
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, wrong paste, corrected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a large CSV file with Scala Stream class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255021/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-scala-stream-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `scala.io.Source`

```
Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()
```

Or you can check `scala.io.BufferedSource.BufferedLineIterator` code and write the same.